# update SSL certificate than can not access to services

Tags: mobile, ssl-certificate, smartface.io

After Secure Socket Layer certificate update, the application can not access to services. What solution would you offer for this problem ?

Comment: We can't offer a solution as you haven't offered any useful troubleshooting information. What's the domain name? What application? What errors do you get?

Comment: You will need to provide much more information about what is not working.

Answer (score -1):

What kind of SSL update did you mean ?

For example, is it only done via ServerSide ?

Maybe, it throws some SSL errors.

You can use ignoreSSLErrors property for better understanding the situation.

Example CodeLine;

```
myWebClient.ignoreSSLErros = true;
```

http://docs.smartface.io/?topic=html/P_SMF_Net_WebClient_ignoreSSLErros.htm

Comment: That's dangerous advice. SSL certificates exist for a reason and validation shouldn't be bypassed.